# react router, redirection, firebase auth and private route : best way to manage it

Tags: reactjs, react-router, firebase-authentication

I'm developping a front-end admin with reactjs and I want to grant access to all pages (including the nav and general template of the page) only if authenticated. If the user is not authenticated I only want to display the login form and nothing more. I've done it like that :

```
render() {

if (this.state.isAuthenticated === false) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

return (
  <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Navigator isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
          <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/shop" exact component={Shop} />
          <Route render={() => <h1>Page not found</h1>} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
 }
 }
```

Is it a good way to do it or is it bad ? How can I do it in a better way ?

Thanks

Comment: I've done a conditionally rendering for two reasons : 
1) I want to hide the navbar / general template of the page and only display the login form (for the moment I dont have any template in the rendering but I'm going to add a more complex structure for the authenticated users) 
2) in my login.js I have a redirection after the authentication (to "/") and the privateroute responding to the path "/" redirects to /login because the router and its routes is rendered before the async changement of state of isAuthenticated